why do i keep getting 400 bad request although my request is correct android
hello im using android app trying to parse the content from this api
BaseURL "https://story-api.dicoding.dev/v1/"
URL
/stories

Parameters
page as int, optional
size as int, optional
location as 1 | 0, optional, default 0
Notes:
1 for get all stories with location
0 for all stories without considering location

Method
GET

Headers
Authorization: Bearer <token>

Response
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "Stories fetched successfully",
    "listStory": [
        {
            "id": "story-FvU4u0Vp2S3PMsFg",
            "name": "Dimas",
            "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "photoUrl": "https://story-api.dicoding.dev/images/stories/photos-1641623658595_dummy-pic.png",
            "createdAt": "2022-01-08T06:34:18.598Z",
            "lat": -10.212,
            "lon": -16.002
        }
    ]
}

i already followed the api doc but i keep getting 400 bad req
this is my logcat
my api service
interface ApiService {
    @GET("stories")
    suspend fun getStories(
        @Header("Authorization") authorization: String,
        @Query("page") page: Int,
        @Query("size") size: Int,
    ): StoryResponse
}

my story repository
class StoryRepository(
    private val apiService: ApiService,
    private val sessionManager: SessionManager  
) {

    suspend fun getStories(token: String): List<ListStoryItem> {
        val token = sessionManager.getToken()  

        val page = 1
        val size = 10

        return apiService.getStories("Bearer $token", page, size).listStory
    }
}

i already test with thunder client and it return 200
this token is from prev test
